# I'm receiving a syntax error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The page is set up to run a simple database query.  The form and the submit button render, but when I type in a search item it returns the error.  The database connect script works well when I use it in my drop down menu to call a query so I'm not certain why it's not working here.

I edited my original post to remove the MySQL and replaced it as follows:  The problem I'm having now is the error is say that I have an undefined variable on line 28 which is if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$output= '';
//collect 
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
}

//Display results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo $result;

}

else {
     echo "0 results";
}


?>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form action="Index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a syntax error.

Comment: Mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code!!!

Comment: both mysqli_* and mysql_* used in your code

Comment: @Saty I saw that and went back in and changed the code as follows:  mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("oldga740_SeniorProject") or die(mysql_error());  I don't get the error now, but my sql_query returns could not search.

Comment: echo your query `echo $sql="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'"` and check your query. Try to run on phpmyadmin and check the result

Comment: Check my edited file please.  I changed the code but it's saying I have an undefined variable now.

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your query

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search");
```

By

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Client LIKE '%".$searchq."%'") or die("could not search");
```

Comment: this feels like a step backwards